# How do I change the highlight color, splash color and size of each Tab in TabBar - Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I can't change the Highlight color and Splash color in AppBar - TabBar for each tab.

Exp:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy3y1.png)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Write all steps and so one. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you will have to use a Custom Indicator for the TabBar or Build your own custom TabBar.

**To use an indicator do:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class BorderTabIndicator extends Decoration {
  BorderTabIndicator({this.indicatorThickness, this.colors,this.tabController}) : super();

  final double indicatorThickness;
  final List<Color> colors;
  final TabController tabController;


  // @override
  _BorderPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback onChanged]) {
    return _BorderPainter(this, indicatorThickness,tabController, colors, onChanged);
  }
}

class _BorderPainter extends BoxPainter {
  _BorderPainter(
    this.decoration,
    this.indicatorThickness,
    this.tabController,
    this.colors,
    VoidCallback onChanged,
  )   : assert(decoration != null),
        assert(indicatorThickness >= 0),
        assert(tabController != null),
        super(onChanged);

  final BorderTabIndicator decoration;
  final double indicatorThickness;
  final List<Color> colors;
  final TabController tabController;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    assert(configuration != null);
    assert(configuration.size != null);
    final start = Offset(offset.dx, configuration.size.height + offset.dy);
    final end = Offset(offset.dx + configuration.size.width, configuration.size.height + offset.dy);
    final paint = Paint();

    paint.color = colors[tabController.index % colors.length];
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = indicatorThickness;
    canvas.drawLine(start,end,paint);
  }
}
```

then in your Tab bar do :

```
indicator: BorderTabIndicator(
                  indicatoThickness: 2,
                  colors: [Colors.red,Colors.blue,Colors.green],
                  controller: _tabController
                )
```

After reviewing my answer i decided to pass the controller instead, to create a controller

```
   this._tabController =
        TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
```

and you can pass it into the BorderTabIndicator.

The TabBar should look like:

```
TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          labelColor: Color(0xff374750),
        
          unselectedLabelColor: Color.fromARGB(143, 51, 71, 70),
          indicator: BorderTabIndicator(
              indicatorThickness: 2,
              colors: [Colors.red, Colors.yellow, Colors.green],
              tabController: widget.tabController),
          controller: widget.tabController,
          onTap: (index) {
            widget.tabController.animateTo(
              index,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            );
          },
          tabs: navigationItems,
        ),
```

you may need to tinker with the solution more to get it working accurately as I didn't run it, however this is the basics of doing that. cheers

my own version of the same solution [Video Demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6bfarHxNUwEao-O7OdksQ7ijAOM0ZoD/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest your read [TabBar Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) for better understanding.